# How to update data into mongodb using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Tried to update value in mongodb using mongoose and nodejs but not working.I do not know how to do it. If anyone know please help me to find solution.

data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.updateData = (req, res, next) => { 
 var uproducts = new updateProduct({
    product_name: collectionDataJSON.product_name 
}); 
updateProduct.updateOne({ p_id: thispid }, uproducts, function(err, raw) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.send(raw);
});
}
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: @Yousaf: No..not getting

Comment: I got the solution using findOne and save method in mongoose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass a mongoose object to the update method, you just need to pass a normal object

something like this

```
module.exports.updateData = (req, res, next) => {
    var uproducts = { // a normal object
        product_name: collectionDataJSON.product_name
    };
    updateProduct.updateOne(
        { p_id: thispid }, // filter part
        { $set: uproducts }, // update part
        function (err, raw) { // call back
            if (err) {
                res.send(err);
            }
            res.send(raw);
        }
    );
}
```

hope it helps

Comment: could you provide a link to the question, please?

Comment: Here we can not share

Comment: this one .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62264996/how-to-get-previous-date-in-javascript ?

Comment: No this one  six225969nine

Comment: could you copy the link and paste it here?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259699/how-to-get-data-from-mongodb-between-including-two-days-in-mongodb-using-mongoos/62260904?noredirect=1#comment110117209_62260904