# How to get previous date in javascript

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have one date but i want to get previous date from that.How we can do using javascript or momentjs?

Demo:https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ykswiz?file=index.js

date format dd-mm-yyyy.

Example:

```
 var date1=new Date("08-06-2020");
 console.log("Prev Date="+date1.getDate() - 1);// Prev Date=07-06-2020


 var date2=new Date("01-06-2020");
 console.log("Prev Date="+date2.getDate() - 1);// Prev Date=31-05-2020


 var date3=new Date("01-01-2021");
 console.log("Prev Date="+date3.getDate() - 1);// Prev Date=31-12-2020
```

Is it possible in javascript?

Comment: Maybe try the [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) library, specifically [`moment.add()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/) :D It will save you lots of trouble

Comment: @BlunderingPhilosopher: Can you edit my code? stackblitz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, if you pass a string to the `new Date()` function, it should be in this format `new Date('MM-dd-yyyy')`

so the first 2 digits represent the month

the second 2 digits represent the date

the next 4 digits represent the year

so `new Date("08-06-2020")` means `August 06, 2020` not `June 08, 2020`

to get the previous day of some date, we can use the moment to subtract 1 day like the following

```
var date1 = new Date('08-06-2020'); // Aug 06, 2020
var date11 = moment(date1).subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');

console.log(`date1 >> ${date1}`);
console.log(`date11 >> ${date11}`);


var date2 = new Date('01-06-2020'); // Jan 06, 2020
var date22 = moment(date2).subtract(1, 'days').format('DD-MM-YYYY');

console.log(`date2 >> ${date2}`);
console.log(`date22 >> ${date22}`);
```

hope it helps

Comment: what does that mean six225969nine?

Comment: Check in the question link..You can find the question  using the number

Comment: could you copy the link and paste it here?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259699/how-to-get-data-from-mongodb-between-including-two-days-in-mongodb-using-mongoos/62260904?noredirect=1#comment110117209_62260904

Answer (score 1):

Since the issue with the Date constructor is explained and solved by one of the above answers, this solution is for the ones who use `moment()` instead of `new Date()`

```
var date = moment('08-06-2020', 'DD-MM-yyyy');

var previousDate = moment(date).subtract(1, 'days');  //derive the previous date
var nextDate = moment(date).add(1, 'days');   //derive the next date

console.log(previousDate.format('DD-MM-yyyy'));  //output => 07-06-2020
console.log(nextDate.format('DD-MM-yyyy'));  //output => 09-06-2020
```

read more about adding and subtracting dates in moment.js

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/subtract/

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

read more about formatting dates in moment.js

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the setDate and getDate functions;

```
var date1=new Date("08-06-2020");
date1.setDate(date1.getDate() - 1);
console.log("Prev Date="+date1.getDate());// Prev Date=08-05-2020
```

hope its what you asked for.
btw, in this format tha previous date will be 08-05-2020 since the default is mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: Not working:https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-f1asdj?file=index.js

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using `momentjs`. Use the moment constructor to parse the input string then use the `subtract()` to subtract the specified number of days from the moment object. Resultant can be formatted according to your requirements

```js
let arr = ["08-06-2020", "01-06-2020", "01-01-2021"];
let prevDates = arr.map(item => {
  let momentItem = moment(item, "DD-MM-YYYY");
  let prevDay = momentItem.subtract(1, "days");
  return prevDay.format("DD-MM-YYYY");
});
console.log(prevDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```